# Rundeck API: edit job description via API call?

Tags: rundeck

I several rundeck jobs I want to change.  Specifically, I want to add a new "on failure" notification.

Is there a way to change a job definition via API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment the only way is to "re-uploading" the modified definition (XML or YAML formats) using `dupeOption=update` on an [import API call](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#importing-jobs).

Example:

```sh
curl -v -H x-rundeck-auth-token:1AjHW1MnLCwKCzxEIANfD43VrDszME3U http://localhost:4440/api/38/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/jobs/import?dupeOption=update -F xmlBatch=@"HelloWorld.xml"
```